# Thread.sleep(xx) but the whole program sleeps?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep

Hey.. i have a program that check-in some people.. if they have a dept, the prog will show a panel with a list..

so i wanna to set the panel not visible after a few seconds.. how could i do that?

I created a new Thread (FadeThread) and started it in the view, but now, when i write

```
Thread.sleep(5000)
```

the whole program sleeps for this 5seconds,.. i only want to wait in the background for 5seconds and set the panel visible(false) but the whole UI and the program sleeps..

Thanks..**.**

Comment: Providing a short code sample would really go a long way in helping us help you :)

Comment: Are you calling *run* instead of *start* (or was it the other way around)? IIRC, if you call *run* directly, it won't actually start a new thread, but just run the threads' "main method" in the context of the current thread.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Thread.sleep()` will suspend the current thread, which I presume is the event dispatcher thread in your case. If you do it in a background thread, it should work, although if you accidentally call `run()` instead of `start()`, it won't.

To execute code with a set delay, you'll have to use the `Timer` class. Much cleaner and you don't have to worry about accidentally creating too many threads, not exiting a thread properly and so on.

Comment: @berry120 Timer is more than enough, and you will of course update the UI using `invokeLater()`.

Comment: @biziclop Good point, updating it using `invokeLater()` would be threadsafe. I'd still advocate using a ScheduledExecutor instead though.

Comment: Let's be clear (because Sun wasn't).  There are two `Timer` classes in the JDK: `java.util.Timer` and `javax.swing.Timer`.  The latter was created specifically to work with Swing UIs: it fires off `ActionEvents` on the EDT so you can safely update components.  See this article for more details: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/timer/

Comment: you are all right - i started the thread with run so it didn't work .. now with .start() it works fine :)

Comment: @berry120: I disagree strongly with your first comment.  Swing Timer's are the simplest and safest way to introduce a simple delay into a Swing program.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels - More than happy to admit that I'm wrong, which I am (was) on this occasion. My brain snapped into java.util.Timer because I was looking at a question on that previously!

Comment: @berry120 To be honest with you, I was thinking of java.util.Timer at first, as a basic introduction to delayed execution.

Answer (score 3):

You are causing the Event Dispatch Thread to sleep so the GUI can't react to events.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for more information and a potential solution.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using Swing, have a look at the [SwingWorker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) class. You can create a process that will block for 5 seconds and then hide the panel in a thread-safe manner.

Alternatively you could used a ScheduledExecutor as long as you make sure you run it on the EDT using `invokeLater()`.